# How do you select a random colortransform from an array and applying it to a movieclip in Flash ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a Tetris game in ActionScript 3. I am using a movieClip and colorTransform array to create colorful, random, unique pieces. Randomizing the frame in the movie clip works well enough, but when I try to apply a random color tint using the clip's colorTransform property, I get this:

```
Tetris.as, Line 342 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type flash.geom:ColorTransform.
```

Here is some sample code:

```
    private function LandTetromino():void
    {
        var cT:int = currentTetromino;
        var landed:Tetris_Shapes;

        for (var i:int=0; i<shapeBuilder[cT][currentRotation].length; i++)
        {
            for (var j:int=0; j<shapeBuilder[cT][currentRotation][i].length; j++)
            {
                if (shapeBuilder[cT][currentRotation][i][j]==1)
                {
                    landed = new Tetris_Shapes();
                    landed.transform.colorTransform = Math.floor(Math.random()*allcolorTransforms.length);
                    landed.gotoAndStop(Math.floor(Math.random()*12));
                    addChild(landed);
                    landed.name="r"+(startingRow+i)+"c"+(startingCol+j);
                    boardArray[startingRow+i][startingCol+j]=1;
                }
            }
        }
        removeChild(tetrisShape);
        dropTime.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, OnTimeTick);
        dropTime.stop();
        CheckForCompleteLines();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allcolorTransforms is ColorTransform Array?

if right. correct follow code.

```
landed.transform.colorTransform = allcolorTransforms[Math.floor(Math.random()*allcolorTransforms.length)];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm used to coding in the .NET framework; actionscript is a little new to me, but I'm enjoying learning it :)